# Use Google volley api to send HTTP POST request of RDF data

Tags: rest, http-post, android-volley, turtle-rdf

So, I have recently integrated the Volley API in my app in order to provide a Cloud storage solution (REST). Since, i have never used the API before i have some trouble trying to send RDF (text/turtle) data via HTTP POST. The REST server is working perfectly since I send GET and POST requests (via the Postman Chrome app) and every time i receive 200 and 201 responses. Although i managed to send a simple GET request via the API, i get a 400 error when i send an HTTP POST.

The code is the following:

```
//the RDF turtle payload to send over HTTP POST
final String bodyPost = "@prefix : <http://xxx.xxx.xxx.gr/xxx/schema/xxx#> ." + "\n" +
                    "@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> ." + "\n" +
                    "[a :Patient ;" + "\n" +
                    ":lastName "+'"'+"Aylakiotis"+'"'+"^^xsd:string ; " + "\n" +
                    ":firstName "+'"'+"Yiannis"+'"'+"^^xsd:string ;" + "\n" +
                    ":dateOfBirth "+'"'+"1970-04-14"+'"'+"^^xsd:date ;" + "\n" +
                    ":amka "+'"'+"12345678903"+'"'+"^^xsd:string ;" + "\n" +
                    ":gender :Male ;" + "\n" +
                    "] .";
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
final String URL ="http://xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/xxx/";
EditText folderTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.folderTitle);
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Object response) {
                    folderTitle.setText("Response is: " + response.toString().substring(0,500));

                }

           }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
               @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   folderTitle.setText("Error: " + error.getMessage());
               }
           }) {



        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            System.out.println("string post data: " + bodyPost);
            if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("string post data: " + bodyPost);
                return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
            }
            return bodyPost.getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String creds = String.format("%s:%s", "xxx", "xxx");
            String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/turtle");
            return headers;
        }

    };

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(strReq);
```

`String bodyPost` is the data payload i want to send in a turtle RDF format. I am putting this in my `getBody()` method, however i still get a 400 bad request. I have already sent this String via POST http through the Postman Chrome app and it works (201 Created). I saw that most implementations had `getParams()` but this requires key/value pairs whereas i am using triples that i want to send as a whole string of raw data

Answer (score 0):

Set your Content-type to text/turtle. Override your request header like this:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    final HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("Content-Type", "text/turtle");
    return params;
}
```